# Capture Html form to PDF ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, asp.net-mvc-5

I am completely new to MVC and need some help with capturing a form to PDF.
I am developing in asp.net MVC 5.

From what I understand I have a form with many different fields such as textboxes,radiobuttons,checkboxes. I dont need to store any of these values within the database as they will not be processed at all so it would not be viable to use a model. Therefore I just need the html form with the filled in values to be captured and converted to PDF.

Essentially I need to capture the filled in form from the browser and the save to pdf. Is there any way I can do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check out this tutorial on exporting a MVC view to PDF using Rotativa - http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/export-asp-net-mvc-view-to-pdf-in-3-quick-steps/. let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi, I've tried it but it only captures the view without any of the filled in values. As the form is quite long it's not really feasible to create a viewmodel with each value.

Comment: I did that by using a viewmodel, I've create a view to fill the data than the user submit that data to an action which return a second view which I printed out like pdf using rotativa.